# Angular - Use service from different module

Tags: angularjs

In Angular I'm building the following module...

```
(function () {
    //TimeTrack Manual
    var app = angular.module('TimeTrack', ['ngRoute', 'toaster']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', { templateUrl: 'Assets/App/Views/Login.html', controller: 'LoginController' })
            .when('/calendar', { templateUrl: 'Assets/App/Views/Calendar.html', controller: 'CalendarController' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: 'login' });
    }]);
}());
```

I'm trying to include the toaster service from the a different module...

```
angular.module('toaster', ['ngAnimate'])
.service('toaster', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.pop = function (type, title, body, timeout, bodyOutputType, clickHandler) {
        this.toast = {
            type: type,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            timeout: timeout,
            bodyOutputType: bodyOutputType,
            clickHandler: clickHandler
        };
        $rootScope.$broadcast('toaster-newToast');
    };

    this.clear = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('toaster-clearToasts');
    };
}])...
```

I've then got my a controller that is attempting to include the toaster service from the toaster module...

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('TimeTrack');

    var LoginController = function ($scope, $http, $location, toaster) {

    };
    app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'toaster', LoginController]);
}());
```

But when this runs I'm getting an error saying "uncaught object".  Can anybody see what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If the toaster-module lives in a different js-file, did you remember to include a script tag for it in index.html?

Comment: I did include the script tag for the toaster module.

Comment: Can you provide a  plunker?

Comment: what is the order that the scripts are listed?

Comment: Should be:  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

Comment: I've put your code into a plunker and it seems to works fine. Please see: http://plnkr.co/edit/3n6D4wsTGV3JnOdj5KF2?p=preview